# How to abstract over higher-kind with F-bounded polymorphism in Scala3? The same definition works in Scala2

Tags: scala, scala-3, gadt, dotty, f-bounded-polymorphism

Assuming that several objects in Scala share an identical definition of nested generic class or trait `H`, with only 1 Peer type defined using F-bounded polymorphism:

```
object Example {

  trait P {

    type H[Peer <: H[Peer]]
  }

  object P1 extends P {
    trait H[Peer <: H[Peer]]
  }
  object P2 extends P {
    trait H[Peer <: H[Peer]]
  }

//  object KO extends P1.HH
}
```

This compiles with absolutely no problem in Scala 2.13.10. But on Scala 3.2.1 it causes the following error:

```
....scala:25:20: Cyclic reference involving type H
one error found
```

What may have caused this definition to violate the underlying type calculus? Can the type system still regard as GADT-friendly if such definition can't be supported?

Comment: probably related to this change: https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/internals/higher-kinded-v2.html

Comment: If `P` is an object, it will be an illegal self-referencing type, however P is not concrete, and the compiler can delay resolution of `H[_]` when P1 & P2 are compiled

Comment: It is not enough that `H` will eventually be resolved at a definition, since the use-side must be considered. Say you have `val x: P`. Then `x.H`'s "kind" is basically `[Peer <: x.H[Peer]] => Type`. The kind contains a non-concrete type `x.H` (it can *never* be resolved to a `class` or `trait`). This is worrying. Scalac goes ahead and assumes it will be fine. Dotty plays it safe and doesn't. I am not sure the underlying (full!) type calculus of Dotty is written down/fixed anywhere.

Comment: Not it is is not written, the DOT logic (or should I call it calculus?) doesn't differentiate between type & trait/class, which makes it even more worrying as GADT works only for traits but not types!

Comment: hmm ... so apparently it is already on the roadmap: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3486610.3486892

Comment: @tribbloid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VV9lPg3fNl8

Comment: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Cyclic+reference+involving https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Cyclic+reference+involving

Comment: @tribbloid Actually, in Scala 2.13 the code stops to compile too, just a little later, when you start to apply it https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/d2HghpuwQBihs2o0Mp1oPA/1

Comment: @tribbloid Why do you consider such kind of definitions useful for GADT?

Comment: @DmytroMitin good question, how about representing inductive conjectures? `type Prime {type Factorial#PlusOne <: Prime}`